# Styling ESlint for vertical dot alignment

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, eslint

## Prelude

I prefer to keep the dots vertically aligned:

```
const my_long_name = louis.what()
                          .a()
                          .wonderful()
                          .world();
```

but ESlint complains

```
`Expected indentation of 4 spaces but found 26. [indent]`.
```

My `~/.eslintrc.js` has

```
module.exports = {
    extends: [
        'airbnb-base',
    ],
    ...
}
```

---

## Question

How can I use `airbnb-base` yet have dots vertically aligned (and have ESlint check for it)?

(Does another style do this out of the box? Writing

```
    extends: [
        'crockford',
    ],
```

didn't work.)

---

## Update 1

If I [write](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/indent#options) in `~/.eslint.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    rules: {
        "indent": ["error", 4, { "MemberExpression": 0 }]
    }
    ...
};
```

the message becomes

```
Expected indentation of 0 spaces but found 26. [indent]
```

and then ESlint is expecting the formatting:

```
const my_long_name = louis.what()
.a()
.wonderful()
.world();
```

Elethan's answer gives a hint for turning off indents in chain calls using:

```
module.exports = {
    rules: {
        "indent": ["error", 4, { "MemberExpression": "off" }]
    }
    ...
};
```

That's better than either continuing to get warnings, or breaking the vertical alignment of dots.

Can one continue to get warnings if the dots are mis-aligned vertically, or is `{ "MemberExpression": "off" }` the best one can do with ESlint in late 2019?

---

## Update 2

I ran `eslint --init` on the following two code samples (and no additional code).

**~/.eslintrc-strictly-four.js**

```
let hello = louis.what()
    .a()
    .wonderful()
    .world();
```

**~/.eslintrc-dots-vertically-aligned.js**

```
let hello = louis.what()
                 .a()
                 .wonderful()
                 .world();
```

and got the following difference:

```
> diff ~/.eslintrc-strictly-four.js ~/.eslintrc-dots-vertically-aligned.js 
61c61
<         "indent": "error",
---
>         "indent": "off",
```

So until someone illuminates this with an authoritative answer, this is the way to do it.

Comment: Try using `louis¶.what()¶.a()¶.wonderful()¶.world()` instead?

Comment: @Bergi I'm not sure of the meaning of a Pilcrow (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pilcrow , or paragraph sign) in the body, rather than a string, of JS code. Care to add a reference?

Comment: The pilcrow represents a line break, which cannot be displayed in a comment.

Comment: @Bergi I see what you mean: add a line break after the object name to simultaneously placate the indent-rule in ESlint and my own need for seeing the dots vertically aligned. It's not quite orthodox, but it does seem to be the best that can be done with ESlint v6.4.0.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like setting the [`MemberExpression` option](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/indent#options) to `off` for the `indent` rule may solve your issue.

> `"MemberExpression"` (default: 1) enforces indentation level for multi-line property chains. This can also be set to `"off"` to disable checking for `MemberExpression` indentation.

For example, in your `.eslintrc`:

```
"rules": {
    "indent": ["error", 4, { "MemberExpression": 0 }]
}
```